# Why do EHT supplies have high internal resistance?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I understand that one of the reasons is safety, as the current flowing through your body in case you touch the terminals will be lower than in a supply with low internal resistance, however, wouldn't low voltage do the same? What is the purpose of "losing volts"?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is an EHT supply?

Comment: Extra high tension supply

Comment: @BobD I was on Event Horizon Telescope.

Comment: @JEB I don't understand your comment. What does Event Horizon Telescope have to do with this.

Comment: If it were low voltage it wouldn't be an EHT supply. You use one if (and only if) you need many kilovolts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however, wouldn't low voltage do the same? What is the purpose of "losing volts"?

Yes, under certain conditions a low voltage source would do the same. But the overall reason is not "losing volts" but limiting current to the body.

Electric shock is caused by current flowing in the body, not voltage. The amount of current flowing through the body depends on the total impedance (body impedance plus source impedance) of the circuit. Body impedance, notably the skin impedance (which can be modeled as a parallel combination of capacitance and resistance) is voltage dependent. The lower the open circuit voltage of the source the greater the skin impedance (assumed dry or slightly moist) and lower the current. So a low voltage source, regardless of its impedance, won't be capable of producing enough body current as long as the skin impedance is not compromised in some way (e.g. by being wet). This only applies to dry to slightly moist skin contact. Not to wet contact and certainly not to immersion conditions.

On the other hand, a high open circuit voltage source such as you EHT supply requires a high source impedance to keep current below electric shock thresholds, because the skin impedance becomes too low. An everyday example of such a source is the insect zapper used outdoors. Its voltage is very high, but so is its impedance thus reducing the risk of severe electric shock to humans.

In addition to the voltage source characteristics, there are many other factors associated with electric shock such as the voltage wave shape, skin conditions, area of contact, etc., and too many more to go into here.

Hope this helps.